# How Convert Microsoft GUID to JAVA UUID?

Tags: java, android

I need to communicate a Guid that was generated in .NET to a Java application.
This is my GUID

> ce095552-b466-4d03-ac41-430ec9286806

and I want to set it to UUID variable !

```
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(stringUUID.getBytes())

UUID.fromString(stringUUID)
```

I am getting error

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""ce095552"

how can I cast GUID to UUID?

Comment: it would be better to add the error message in the question rather than give an external link

Comment: UUIDs are usually a random string formatted a bit. Just take it as a string, no need to convert it.

Answer (score 3):

When you get some *Microsoft objectGUIDs* , Active Directory objectGUID of the group object for example, you need to get the binary and then convert it to hexadecimal after then you need generate a [MS GUID](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1109/windows/active-directory/java-ldap-jndi-2-ways-of-decoding-and-using-the-objectguid-from-windows-active-directory/) (look at order byte sequence inside *convertToDashedString* function).

The byte order comparing UUID and GUID is different: try convert it using online converters like: [robobunny converter](http://robobunny.com/cgi-bin/guid)

Now I'm storing and working with *ms guid*

```
public static String convertMSGUIDToHexFormat(String guid){
    guid = guid.replaceAll("-", "");
    guid = guid.replaceAll("(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5").replaceAll("(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2}).(.{2})(.{2}).(.{2})(.{2})(.{18})", "$4$3$2$1-$6$5-$8$7$9");
    guid = guid.replaceAll("-", "");
    return guid;
}

public static String convertHexToMSGUIDFormat(String hex){
    return hex.replaceAll("(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5").replaceAll("(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2}).(.{2})(.{2}).(.{2})(.{2})(.{18})", "$4$3$2$1-$6$5-$8$7$9");
}
```

When I know a better way, then I change that supposed quick fix

Answer (score 1):

[`UUID.fromString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String)) works fine:

```
String guid = "ce095552-b466-4d03-ac41-430ec9286806";
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(guid);

System.out.println(uuid);
```

Comment: ok , But i want to get GUID from JSON Recived from the Web Service, and set it to my object UUID property!

Comment: @AsadKarami No idea what you mean. Your receive the GUID in your JSON as a string, no? And what is your object UUID property? Just a member field of type `java.util.UUID`? What's the problem? Your question asks how to convert a GUID string to a UUID object and provides no further information.

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid long: ""ce095552"

Looks like the GUID you are passing to `UUID.fromString` still includes quotes ("). Make sure the GUID string does not include any additional characters and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String guid = "41e72bd6-d38f-4f78-855f-160562262a54";
 UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(guid);
 ReadValueId readValueId = new ReadValueId(
 new NodeId(2, uuid),
 AttributeId.Value.uid(), null, QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE);
```

Comment: Please, try to not answer with code only, even if the code may work. Could you add text/link to docs?. Thanks.